# Print Bootstrap 3 Tabs Component using only one foreach Loop

Tags: php

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to build a tab-panel component, based on information coming from the end-user. I don't like how there's a second foreach loop, but I don't know how else to print the HTML correctly.

Given an array structured like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "content": "Lorem Ipsum"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "content": "Lorem Ipsum"
    }
]
```

And a "view" template structured like this:

```
<?php $panels = rwmb_meta("ssc_tabpanels") ?>
<?php if( !empty($panels) ): ?>
    <div id="program-details">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
            <?php foreach($panels as $i => $p): ?>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#tab-<?php echo $i ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $p['title'] ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <?php foreach($panels as $i => $p): ?>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $p['content'] ?></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What suggestions do you have for removing the second `foreach` loop while still maintaining the correct bootstrap code?

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to build the value of the tab contents in a variable during the first loop, and just print it once the loop ends.  I have not written PHP in a while nor tested this code, so use as reference.

```
<?php $panels = rwmb_meta("ssc_tabpanels") ?>
<?php $tabContentHtm = ''; ?>
<?php if( !empty($panels) ): ?>
<div id="program-details">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
        <?php
        //build the tabs    
        foreach($panels as $i => $p):
        ?>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#tab-<?php echo $i ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $p['title'] ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php
        // build content displayed on click of each tab
        $tabContentHtm .= '<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-'. $i .'">'. $p['content'] .'</div>\r\n';
        endforeach; 
        ?>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php echo $tabContentHtm; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The rendered code should look something like this

```
<div id="program-details">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Title 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Title 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-1">Lorem Ipsum of Title 1</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">Lorem Ipsum of Title 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP also has a [short open tag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) that I would use for `echo`.

```
<?= $p['content'] ?>
```

Comment: I'm stuck supporting 5.3 at the moment, so I can't guarantee that that it's available. 5.4 guarantees that. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a function that re-ordered the array into a structure like

```
{
    "list-items": [ "<li ...><a ...>Title</a></li>", ... ],
    "pane-items": [ "<div ...>Content</div>", ... ]
}
```

And then in the theme I used `implode("\n", $items['list-items'])` and `implode("\n", $items['pane-items'])` where appropriate.

### Code

```
/**
 * @param array $panels
 * @return array
 */
function restructure_panels( array $panels )
{

    $result = array(
        "list-items" => array(),
        "pane-items" => array()
    );

    $active = true;
    array_map(function ($k, $v) use (&$result, &$active) {

        if (!empty($v['title']) && !empty($v['content'])) {

            $classes = "";
            if ($active)
                $classes = " active";

            $result['list-items'][] = "<li role=\"presentation\" class=\"{$classes}\"><a href=\"#tab-{$k}\" data-toggle=\"tab\">{$v['title']}</a></li>";
            $result['pane-items'][] = "<div class=\"tab-pane {$classes}\" id=\"tab-{$k}\">{$v['content']}</div>";

            $active = false;
        }

    }, array_keys($panels), $panels);

    return $result;

}
```

// in single-program.php

```
<?php $panels = restructure_panels( rwmb_meta("ssc_tabpanels") ) ?>

<?php if( !empty($panels) ): ?>
    <div id="program-details" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                 <?php echo implode( "\n", $panels['list-items'] ); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <?php echo implode( "\n", $panels['pane-items'] ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```